# Index multiple tables from MySQL to elasticsearch using jdbc river

Tags: sql, node.js, jdbc, elasticsearch

I need to fetch data from MySQL to Elasticsearch, i am use Elasticsearch jdbc plugin for that. This plugin allows to set a query for getting data from MySQL, but query allows to get data only from one table, and i have over 20 tables to fetch from. How can i index multiple tables in series? When I'am trying to add river for each table, indexing causes high CPU usage.

Comment: What do you mean, "index multiple tables in [a] series?" It sounds like you've got a lot of data in 20+ tables. Is this just an initial load or is the quantity of data always high?

Comment: i mean, that i have many tables in MySQL and i need to fetch data from them to Elasticsearch successively, one by one, because when i run multiple rivers in parallel, it causes high CPU usage. Are there any ways to do this?

Answer (score 0):

"This plugin allows to set a query for getting data from MySQL"
If I understand your question correctly, you should try inner join, or where statement to join tables in one query.

For example:
SELECT * FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.ID = table2.ID
  WHERE table1.amount > 5000

Comment: No, i need to fetch data from separate tables, it must be multiple sql statements, which will be executed in series.